# Why are my new Azure end points not working?

Tags: azure

I have two virtual machines hosted on Azure, and I'm trying to set up new endpoints for one of them. I've successfully created the end points but the connections won't go through. I've used tcpdump to verify that the SYN packets are not even reaching the VM. I don't have a firewall configured on the VM either. All my existing end points work fine, and if I delete one of them, it stops receiving connections. I just can't add any new, working endpoints.

So I tried the same with my second VM and everything works as expected there. The only difference between them is that VM #2 has end points 22, 80, 19000, 19001 while the problematic VM #1 has 80, 443, 19000 and 19001.

What could I be possibly doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: This should be moved to ServerFault. That said: Please edit your question to show your complete endpoint mapping (external ip, internal ip, whether port-forwarded or load-balanced, protocol) for each.

Comment: I posted this same question on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/542535/why-are-my-new-azure-end-points-not-working

Answer (score 1):

It seems it was a glitch in Azure. It was fixed during a maintenance run.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure windows firewall isn't blocking your entry / exit for the endpoints? check it first, then if still having issue start analyzing with Microsoft Message Analyzer (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40308
) on both ends, just to make sure.

Comment: Windows isn't involved. It's a Ubuntu server, just like the other one.